# "When I was in third year at the University".: Is "my" necessary here like "in my third year""

Tags: possessives

Is "my" really necessary in this sentence : " When I was (in third year,in MY third year) at the university" .If it is then why do we need to use  'my'?

Comment: Please clarify. Your *first* question asks *whether* "my" is needed in the sentence. Your *second* question asks *why* "my" is needed "**here**". What does "here" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The question is "Can I refer to a **specific** thing without using a determiner?" And the answer must be No: a determiner is always necessary to specify the thing referred to. There's a clue in the very name *determiner:* that which determines.

Thus, to answer your specific question, if you want to refer to a specific "third year" — yours as opposed to anyone else's — you need a determiner like *my* or possibly *the*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, the meanings being slightly different.

```
in third year at University
```

Here we are giving a name to that year, "third year" is, obviously, the third year of studies. It is equivalent to the American "in junior year at University." The specific period is being named.

```
in my third year at University
```

This means the third year you have spent there.

Let's say you were a poor student and failed your examinations, but had lots of money. You tried to pass the first year of courses twice and were studying again to give it a third try. Here you would be in "first year" or "freshman year" at the University even though you are in "your third year".